# example of a function satisfying certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation, harmonic-analysis

Does there exist a function $h\in C(0,1)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x)=\infty$ and satisfying the following condintion
$$
n\int_0^1 e^{-nx} h(x) dx<C,\,\forall n>>1.
$$

P.s. I think such a function does exist due to the exponential decay in front. However, I am unable to construct it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $h$ is non-negative we have $n\int_0^{1}e^{-nx}h(x)dx=\int_0^{n}e^{-y}h(\frac y n)dy\geq \int_0^{\sqrt n}e^{-y}h(\frac y n)dy\geq c_n \int_0^{\sqrt n}e^{-y}dy$ where $c_n=\inf \{h(t): 0<t<\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\}$.Since, $c_n \to \infty$ it follows that $n\int_0^{1}e^{-nx}h(x)dx \to \infty$.

Comment: The argument above has a small problem, namely that $h$ can be negative away from zero - if $h$ is bounded near $1$ the fix is very easy since $h$ is indeed eventually positive but if $h$ is allowed to go to minus infinity at $1$, not sure